# Importance of Akka Routers

Tags: scala, akka, actor

I have this lingering doubt in my mind about the importance of `Akka` Routers. I have used Akka Routers in the current project I am working on. However, I am a little confused about the importance of it. Out of the two below methods, which is more beneficial.

1. having routers and routees.
2. Creating as many actors as needed.

I understood that router will assign the incoming messages among its routees based on the strategy. Also, we can have supervisor strategy based on the router. 
I have also understood that actors are also lightweight and it is not an overhead to create as many actors as possible. So, we can create actors for each of the incoming messages and kill it if necessary after the processing si completed.

So I want to understand which one of the above design is better? Or in other words, in which case (1) has advantage over (2) OR vice versa.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Good question. I had similar doubts before I read Akka documentation. Here are the reasons:

1. **Efficiency**. From [docs](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/snapshot/scala/routing.html):

   > On the surface routers look like normal actors, but they are actually
   >   implemented differently. Routers are designed to be extremely
   >   efficient at receiving messages and passing them quickly on to
   >   routees.
   >
   > A normal actor can be used for routing messages, but an actor's
   >   single-threaded processing can become a bottleneck. Routers can
   >   achieve much higher throughput with an optimization to the usual
   >   message-processing pipeline that allows concurrent routing. This is
   >   achieved by embedding routers' routing logic directly in their
   >   ActorRef rather than in the router actor. Messages sent to a router's
   >   ActorRef can be immediately routed to the routee, bypassing the
   >   single-threaded router actor entirely.
   >
   > The cost to this is, of course, that the internals of routing code are
   >   more complicated than if routers were implemented with normal actors.
   >   Fortunately all of this complexity is invisible to consumers of the
   >   routing API. However, it is something to be aware of when implementing
   >   your own routers.
2. **Default implementation** of multiple routing strategies. You can always write your own, but it might get tricky. You have to take into account supervision, recovery, load balancing, remote deployment, etc.
3. Akka Router patterns will be **familiar** to Akka users. If you roll-out your custom routing then everyone will have to spend time understanding all corner cases and implications (+ testing? :)).

TL;DR If you don't care about efficiency too much and if it's easier for you to spawn new actors then go for it. Otherwise use Routers.

Comment: Thanks Aleksey, for the explanation. I now understood how an actor s different from router. But still have one confusion. How does routers improve performance, since we can create as many actors to do the processing when required without any overhead? I guess routers can bring in fault tolerance, but other than that anything else ?

Comment: Creating actors is very cheap and not a concern here. Routers improve performance in message routing by essentially forwarding a message directly from client to worker "bypassing" routing actor. If you implement routing using regular actor all messages will have to queue on its mailbox and be forwarded to workers, that is an extra hop that you might want to avoid. Schematically: `Client->(AkkaRouter)->Worker` vs `Client->YourRouter->Worker`. Where `(X)` means a hop that will be bypassed.

Comment: What if I implement "actors per request" ? In that case, each actor will handle only one request and can be killed after that? Will it perform better than having routers ?

Comment: If you need a central location/address for your actor then again messages will go through it's queue and will have the same slowdown. If you can avoid that (single `ActorRef`/custom router) and just spawn actors and let them reply directly back then you'll have the same efficiency as Akka Routers. Anyway, even if you build a custom router without implementing it on top of Akka Router and efficiently forward messages to worker actors without delays the slowdown might really not be noticeable. Usually time spent doing IO will be the main consideration and not message forwarding.